# Neo4J query to join multiple matches to return results

Tags: neo4j, cypher

When I run the query below
query 1  is producing result returning all categories label for a document for all documents. Note a document can have multiple categories hence collecting them in on go.

```
START doc = node:entities(type = "document-link")
MATCH  category-[:category]-doc<-[:`document-link`]-id
RETURN 
  doc.title    as title,
  COLLECT(COALESCE(category.category, "")) as categories
```

query 2  is producing result returning language of the document for all documents. A document can have only one language type.

```
START  doc = node:entities(type = "document-link")
MATCH  lan-[:language]-doc<-[:`document-link`]-id
RETURN 
  doc.title    as title,
  lan.language as language
```

query 3 which is join of 1 and 2 is producing empty result. Can someone highlight what I am doing wrong?

```
START  doc = node:entities(type = "document-link")
MATCH  category-[:category]-lan-[:language]-doc<-[:`document-link`]-id
RETURN 
doc.title    as title,
lan.language as language,
COLLECT(COALESCE(category.category, "")) as categories
```

Comment: the ? in match and ! on properties is outdated syntax for versio 1.9 and before, please update to a recent version like 2.1.6

Answer (score 1):

In your third query you match on a relation between category and a language, which you don't do in your first 2 queries. How about this:

```
START  doc = node:entities(type = "document-link")
MATCH category-[:category]-doc<-[:`document-link`]-id
MATCH doc-[:language]-lan
RETURN 
doc.title    as title,
lan.language as language,
COLLECT(COALESCE(category.category, "")) as categories
```

Comment: Thanks this worked. Btw, I was doing debugging on neo4j and where I am trying to modify an existing cypher but the debugger complains when I use "?" in the Match recommending to use optional match also in result use of "?" or "!" also fails but it works in the code. Do you know the reason for that for example category can have null fields or title may be empty and I may want to inserting something instead of null. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: If it worked, please accept and upvote the answer :). As for this question, I'm not entirely sure. As far as I know, null value fields are not even allowed. Perhaps you can post your additional question right here on stackoverflow :)